# Python dict remove inline without modifying

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Since Python 3.5, we can merge two dictionaries inline without modifying the original ones by doing

```
z = {**x, **y}
```

[From Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#dictionary-merge-update-operators), this will be even easier with the merge `|` operator.

Is there a way to do the opposite, i.e. an inline expression for 'give me the dict `x` without key `a` and without modifying `x`?'

Comment: How about `{k: v for k, v in x.items() if k != a} `?

Comment: Additional set operations, including `-`, were [explicitly mentioned](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#what-about-the-full-set-api) in the PEP for the new features you mention. **TL;DR**: not yet.

Comment: Thx for the reference :) editor mentioned the pep, haven't looked at it yet. Just found the statement about 3.9 somewhere else on stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the pep, 'subtracting' from a dict by using `-` has not been realized yet as @jonrsharpe highlighted. Instead, building upon the solution of @Warren Weckesser, currently the most concise solution for subtracting a set of keys from a dict is

```
{key: value for key, value in my_dict.items() if key not in [key1, key2]}
```